# Common component - Infinite intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is usually said in the context of Bezout's theorem that a system of polynomial equations will only have continuously infinite solutions if the polynomials have a common component. In the below example 
$$x^{2}+xz-x=0$$
$$yz+xy-y=0$$
$$xy-z=0$$
We have the infinite set of solutions given by 
$$x=t$$
$$y=1/t-1$$
$$z=1-t$$
for all $t$. It appears to me that the poynomials don't share a common component? 
Even if they do, this solution above is one dimensional, but if it's just the zero locus of the common component, then shouldn't it be two dimensional?

*It seems clear from the answers that I have confused common component with common factor. Is it correct to say: the polynomials share a common component, namely the set I parametrised with $t$, but they do not share a common factor?

Comment: You are confusing what a common component means. If you have a bunch of polynomials, they may all vanish at infinitely many points even though the defining polynomials may have no common factors.

Comment: Could you help clarify what a common component is then?

Comment: Is this to say that a common factor is sufficient but not necessary for infinitely many solutions?

Comment: For instance, take $x=0,y=0$ in 3-space. If you think we should take 3 equations for 3 spaces, take $x=0, y=0, x+y=0$.  Of course, if you have a common factor for all the polynomials and there are at least 2 variables, then you get infinitely many solutions.

Comment: The two first quadrics have a common factor, the plane $x+z-1$, and this intersects the third quadric resulting in a conic in this plane. And then theres's an embedded point; the origin, because the other intersection of the first two quadrics is the line $x=0,y=0$ that also intersects the third quadric there. Your parametrization is of the conic.

Comment: So if i have a system of polynomial equations, what kind of algorithm would I use to determine whether they have a positive dimensional common component?